# multilevel models - correlation between units and groups

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, estimation, multilevel-analysis, bias

I read in a paper that an important issue in multilevel modelling is the potential correlation between the predictors $X_{ij}$ and $u_{j}$, the residual component of the group levels.

The multilevel equation being

$Y_{if} = β_{0} + B_{1}X_{ij} + B_{2}Z_{j} + u_{j}$

with $Z_{j}$ the group level co-variates.

1. Firstly, I'm having trouble finding examples of such a potential correlation. Could someone give me some examples of potential correlations between $X_{ij}$ and $u_{j}$ that could bias estimates?
2. Secondly, some authors proposed to construct aggregate contextual variables by computing the mean of covariates to solve this issue. 
   However, I fail to understand why including the aggregate mean of co-variables solve the problem of correlation between $X_{ij}$ and $u_{j}$.
3. Finally, what should I do if my co-variates are categorical. How I am suppose to aggregate them?

To tell you a little bit more about my data.

I am working with couple data, where my levels are households. So, I have individuals embedded in households. My dependant variable ($y_{ij}$) is a numerical scale reflecting the general health status of the individual. 
Any idea how this correlation problem could apply here?

```
couple id  sex   health
 1      1  male    9
 1      2  female  7
 2      1  male    6
 2      2  female  5
 3      1  male    4
 3      2  female  4
 ....
```

Comment: How do you  compute potential correlation under point 1 ?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't think you can really compute it. It is an assumption - an unobserved correlation.